# InternalError: too much recursion when sending an crypted object in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, cryptojs

I'm trying to send crypted file that I have uploaded from client to `node.js` server, but everytime I get the error:

> InternalError: too much recursion

I've crypted uploaded file using `Crypto-JS` library:
**main.js**

```js
function loaded(evt) {

    var arrayFileBuffer = evt.target.result;

    var arrayFileTyped = new Uint8Array(arrayFileBuffer);

    var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(arrayFileTyped);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, m_secret_key_x.toString());

    socket.emit('send_file', encrypted);

}
```

And the `socket.emit('send_file', encrypted)` is the part where it crashes. 
In Mozilla Firebug, I can see that function `_hasBinary()` from `Socket.IO` has been called numerous times and I think it's causing too much recursion error.

Any help with solving this problem would be appreciated, thank you in advance!